# Multiple root route for FOSRestBundle

Tags: rest, api, symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I'm using the FOSRestBundle and I can't find how to have two different endpoint, one for the template rendering (html/twig, `/app` for example) and another one for the serialization (json, `/api` for example). Is it possible ? The documentation for [FOSRestBundle Automatic Route generation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html), does not indicate any of this.

Using Symfony 3 and FOSRestBundle 2.x

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this via format listeners in your app/config.yml.

```
fos_rest:
  format_listener:
    rules:
        - { path: '^/api', priorities: [json], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
        - { path: '^/', priorities: ['text/html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
  param_fetcher_listener: force
  view:
    view_response_listener: force
    formats:
        json: true
        html: true
```

About the routing part, here's an example of one controller with two actions, one for each type of response (annotations):

```
namespace RVW\AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class BrandController extends FOSRestController
{
  /**
   * @param Request $request
   * @View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_OK)
   * @Route("/brands", name="brands")
   * @Method({"GET"})
   *
   * @return View
   */
  public function brandsAction(Request $request): View
  {
    return $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('AppBundle:Brand')->findAll();
  }

  /**
   * @Route("/", name="index")
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function indexAction(Request $request): Response
  {
    return $this->render('@App/index.html.twig', [
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! I saw that in the doc, but what about the routing part? I found a workaround where I define 2 routes one with the `type: rest` at `/api` and another one with non-rest routing configuration (loading the controller's actions)  at `/app`, keeping the same controller

Comment: I edited the answer adding more info about routing. Just return a fosrestview or render a html view in each action. If you are not using annotations you will have to "translate" it to routing.yml syntax.

Comment: @Thiryn accept the answer if solved your problem to close the question.

Comment: I guess @Thiryn wants all REST routes to start with "/api" and all other routes to start with "/app". I thought adding in `routing.yml` an `api: type: rest resource: AppBundle\Controller\RestController` would work (I feel it did work in previous versions of the RESTBundle and/or Symfony)

Comment: I remembered how to do it, see my answer below

Answer (score -1):

Simply specify a `prefix` in your routing configuration.

If you're using YAML, you can change your `routing.yml` file:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type:      annotation
    prefix:    /app

api:
    type:     rest
    resource: AppBundle\Controller\RestController
    prefix:   /api
```

Now your normal routes start with `/app` and your REST routes start with `/api`